# MySQL returning all the records from the left table excluding the records that have a match in the right table

Tags: mysql

I am trying to return records from **Table1** where there is not a match in **Table2**.

**SQL:**

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1 c
LEFT JOIN
Table2 a
ON c.TableID = a.TableID
WHERE c.TableID NOT IN (SELECT a.TableID FROM Table2)
```

I have tried to right this many times without success. Can anyone please help?

Many thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Just make the where condition as `where  a.TableID is null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace 'where' with this:

```
WHERE a.TableID IS NULL
```